# SharePoint Designer Workflow actions - how to get substring from start of variable until character "|"

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer

Any way to get the susbstring from the start of the string until a specific character in a SharePoint designer workflow action? I cannot use "**Extract Substring from Start of String**" because there isn't a set number of characters I want to copy.

I need to get "1 Year" or "3 Months" from the below strings:

**"1 Year|5ff55ee4-5a60-2132-bc02-bbfdd9f190ab"**

**"3 Months|b553caa2-fww7-4c7f-b84e-22788d26386a"**

Comment: has any one got something on above? Please let me know.. additionally NO CODE DEPLOYMENT option.... Thank You. Addtionally my initial part is keep on changing.. i mean it will be like John Cena|5ff55ee4-5a60-2132-bc02-bbfdd9f190ab david mcarther|5ff55ee4-5a60-2132-bc02-bbfdd9f190ab ross kapito|5ff55ee4-5a60-2132-bc02-bbfdd9f190ab

Comment: What version of SharePoint and are you doing a 2010 or 2013 style workflow?

Comment: Can someone tell how to do this in SharePoint Designer 2010 as suggested by user17734?

Comment: in a 2010 workflow there is no 'FIND' Action i.e. this is not possible:   
   then Find substring in string (Output to Variable: index1)                             Use a 2013 workflow instead to achieve this

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

1) **Find substring in string** in which:

- substring is just the pipe | character
- string is your metadatafield_0 field
- output: index1

2) **Extract substring from string with length** in which:

- substring is your metadata_0 field from the current item
- starting location is 0
- end is the output of the first step (index1)
- output: substring1

Now log substring1. In my case this results exactly in all characters in front of the pipe character:)

Comment: I'm unable to find the action "Find substring in string". Is this a default action in SharePoint 2010 (Foundation)?

Comment: Neat- Just done this as a 2013 workflow updating title on a lookup list with a MMS column

Comment: @TempaC I believe this is only available with SP 2013 Workflows.

Answer (score 7):

- **Find substring in string**
  [image]
  **Substring**= |
  **string**=**1 Year|5ff55ee4-5a60-2132-bc02-bbfdd9f190ab**

  here you will get the index of "**|**"
- Now pass that index in **Extract string from start of string**
  [image]

  replace **0** with your index number, i.e. **variable:index1**

  **string**=**1 Year|5ff55ee4-5a60-2132-bc02-bbfdd9f190ab**

  [image]

so you will get your output in **variable:substring2** is **1 Year**

substring is just the pipe | character
string is your metadatafield_0 field
output: index1

Comment: How can we do the same thing in sharepoint designer 2010 ?

Comment: You might just need to download Sharepoint Designer 2013.  In SPD 2013 you can also create/modify 2010 workflows.  I use SPD 2013 but 95% of the workflows I use are using the 2010 'architecture'.

Answer (score 3):

In Sharepoint 2013 workflow:

1- Find the index of pipe "|" and save it to a variable.

2- Use an action called "Extract Substring from String from Index with Length".

3- Set copy from to be one of your original strings "1 Year|5ff55ee4-5a60-2132-bc02-bbfdd9f190ab" or "3 Months|b553caa2-fww7-4c7f-b84e-22788d26386a".

4- Set copy starting at to be 0.

5- Set for (length) to be the pipe index variable.

The output will be the part of the original string preceding the pip.