# User's Display Name in SharePoint designer Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, sharepoint-designer-workflow, person-or-group

Is it possible to change Users's display name in SharePoint workflow to first name & last name only?

Currently it is shown as "LastName,Firstname domain".

For example:

Current: Kumar, Ashok XYZ (here XYZ is domain Name)

Required: Ashok Kumar

Comment: Are you using SP designer 2013 WF? Are you trying to get the display name from Person or Group field?

Comment: yes using Sp designer WF and people picker as a column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all try fetching the display name of Person or Group field like given in below image:

[image]

If this is not working for you then you need to extract the First Name and Last Name from the string you are getting as a output from above image.

You need to use below actions for that:

1. Set the Display name (same as above image) in a workflow variable.
2. Find the index of `Domain` from above variable.
3. Extract the sub-string from the variable.
4. You can do similar steps if you want to get the First Name and Last Name in separate variable by finding the index of comma(,) and then extracting sub-string.

**Reference of Actions**: [Utility actions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/workflow-actions-quick-reference-sharepoint-workflow-platform#utility-actions).

Example: [SharePoint Designer Workflow actions - how to get substring from start of variable until character "|"](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/61948/sharepoint-designer-workflow-actions-how-to-get-substring-from-start-of-variab)

Comment: this is useful , let me try this and get the output

Comment: Sure, try it and let me know if there is any problems doing it this way.

Comment: Have you tried this? Is it working for you?

Comment: yes it is working let me mark as answer